android NFC payment callback
Is there any way to receive the payment information ?
When I go to the shop and paying with my phone is there any way to run another application in the background and receive the informations like where did I pay and how much did I pay?
I don't want to handle the payment process its enought to me if wallet handles it I just want to get a copy of that data.
I tried to use android studio NFC but im not sure if its possible with that or not.
